# Assign variable separated by comma based on user input using function

Tags: linux, bash

I wanted to assign variable name separated by comma based on user input using function.
I will get the user input using below script and it will call function for variable assignment

```
while [ "$ans" != "q" ]
do
clear
echo "Choose your subject"
echo "Press q once done"
echo " 1.Science"
echo " 2.Maths"
echo " 3.English"
...
read ans
case $ans in
1) clear
Science;;
2) clear
Maths;;
3) clear
English;;
....
esac
done
clear

subjects=""

Science()
{
subjects+="$subjects Science"
}
Maths()
{
subjects+="$subjects Maths"
}
English()
{
subjects+="$subjects English"
}
```

At the end I wanted to have variable subjects to have option choose by the user:

Etc:

Science,Maths

Maths,English

Science,English

English

Comment: Is there an error or difficulty or are you stuck at something?

Comment: No error but there was no value assign to the subjects variable

Comment: https://shellcheck.net

Comment: Thanks Jetchisel, you give me some idea on this, I manage to get the variable value without call the function, [link] https://dzone.com/articles/shell-create-a-comma-separated-string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. In *bash*, the function definition must be placed *before* any calls to the function.
2. The line `subjects=""` must be placed *before* the `while` loop. Otherwise its value will get lost (will be set to empty string) on exit from the loop.
3. The `+=` operator causes double concatenation in the line `subjects+="$subjects Science"`, since the right hand side contains already the expansion of the `subjects` variable. Either `subjects="$subjects Science"`, or `subjects+=" Science"` must have been used (the same is also true for other lines in which the `+=` operator is used). Besides, since a comma separated list is desired, a `,` character must be used while concatenating strings instead of space character. For example: `subjects="$subjects,Science"`

So a corrected script could be like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

subjects=""

Science() {
    subjects="$subjects,Science"
}

Maths() {
    subjects="$subjects,Maths"
}

English() {
    subjects="$subjects,English"
}

while [ "$ans" != "q" ]; do
    clear
    echo "Choose your subject"
    echo "Press q once done"
    echo " 1.Science"
    echo " 2.Maths"
    echo " 3.English"

    read -r ans
    case $ans in
        1) Science;;
        2) Maths;;
        3) English;;
    esac
done

subjects=${subjects:1}  # to remove the leading ',' character
echo "Your selections are $subjects"
```

Note: I wouldn't normally use a function just to append a simple string to a variable.

Comment: Thanks M.Nejat Aydin, this solution works! Fyi, I also manage to get it done without using function:

<code>
read -r ans
case $ans in
1) clear
subjects="${subjects}${subjects:+,}Science";;
2) clear
subjects="${subjects}${subjects:+,}Maths";;
3) clear
subjects="${subjects}${subjects:+,}English";;
esac
done
</code>

Comment: Glad to hear that.